# Click Event for MaterialButton on C# Xamarin Android App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, button

The application is attempting to pull data from `edittext1` and `edittime` and use that data once the `button1` has been pressed.

The issue I'm having is that I do not know how to get the `FindTranslator` function to execute upon pressing the button or how to pull data from those textfields.

C# Code:

```
namespace Case_Study
{
  [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
  public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
  {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
      // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
      SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        View btn = FindViewById<Google.Android.Material.Button.MaterialButton (Resource.Id.button1);
        //btn.SetOnClickListener(new IOnClickListener()
    }
            
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
      Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
      base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
            
    public void FindTranslator()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Button Clicked");
    }
  }
}
```

Layout Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation = "vertical">
  <TextView
    android:text="Enter Hospital"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/textdate"
    android:gravity="center" />
  <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText1" />
  <TextView
    android:text="Enter Duration in Minutes"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textduration"
    android:gravity = "center" />
  <EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edittime" />
  <CheckBox
    android:text="In-Person"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1" />
  <CheckBox
    android:text="Spanish"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2" />
  <Button
    android:text="Find Translator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use the button's `Clicked` event to call the `FindTranslator` method.  You can retrieve the values of the text controls by using their `Text` properties.  There are numerous samples of interacting with the Android UI in the Xamarin docs and elsewhere on the web.